# How do proponents of eternal conscious torment/separation reconcile their beliefs with Luke 13:3, 5?

Tags: eschatology, hell, words-of-jesus, repentance

> Luke 13:1-5 There were some present at that very time who told him about the Galileans whose blood Pilate had mingled with their sacrifices. 2 And he answered them, “**Do you think that these Galileans were worse sinners than all the other Galileans, because they suffered in this way**? 3 No, I tell you; **but unless you repent, you will all likewise perish**. 4 Or those eighteen on whom the tower in Siloam fell and killed them: **do you think that they were worse offenders than all the others who lived in Jerusalem**? 5 No, I tell you; **but unless you repent, you will all likewise perish**.”

Jesus, after asking His disciples whether the Galileans who were killed by Pilates were worse sinners than others due to suffering in such a manner, tells them that, unless they repent, they will all perish in like manner. He goes on to ask His disciples whether the eighteen who died when the tower in Siloam fell and killed them were worse sinners than others due to being killed in such a manner, then tells them that unless they repent, they will all perish in like manner. The "likewise" clearly denotes dying in a similar manner, that is, in an intense and brutal manner(and I hope I don't have to point out that being *consciously separated from the presence of God* is not "likewise perishing").

How does one reconcile this teaching with traditional eternal conscious torment/separation, which asserts that the wicked will live for eternity in immortal bodies? I'm sure many will say that Jesus means His disciples will "likewise perish" *in this life* and that He is not talking about the final judgment. However, this interpretation is untenable for several reasons.

**(1)** Jesus says that unless they repent, they WILL perish violently as did the Galileans who were killed by Pilate and the eighteen whom the tower fell on. Jesus is assuring His disciples that if they do not repent, they *will* perish in a violent manner. If the "perishing" applies only to this life, then Jesus is saying that everyone who does not repent will perish in a violent manner *in this life*. But this is clearly not true. Many, many unrepentant people live to old age and die peacefully in their sleep, **not** in a brutal manner as did the Galileans and eighteen.

**(2)** When Jesus says that UNLESS they repent they will die violently, He is implying that if they DO repent they will **not** die violently, is He not? Jesus is attempting to motivate His disciples to repentance, and He does so by assuring them that if they do NOT repent, they will die brutally as did the Galileans and eighteen. In doing so, He is assuring them that if they DO repent, they will not die brutally in this life as the Galileans and eighteen did. But this simply doesn't concur with historical facts(it doesn't even agree with Jesus' own teachings[see Matthew 10:21, Luke 21:16]). Christian have, throughout the centuries, died incredibly brutal deaths! Jesus' words here, if applying only to this life, are plainly false(and utterly meaningless)!

**(3)** The interpretation that Jesus' words apply only to this life doesn't even agree with what Jesus was teaching His disciples in this very passage. The assumption by everyone is that, if you die a brutal death, God must be angry at you for your sins and has decided to punish you(many people still believe this today); dying in a violent manner is an indication that you are a terrible sinner, and God has simply punished you for it. But Jesus tells His disciples, "NO, I tell you, unless YOU repent, you will all likewise perish". Jesus was saying that there wasn't anything special about the Galileans or the eighteen with regards to sin that caused them to die in such a manner; "you all are just like them, sinners who will all likewise perish unless there is repentance on your part". Jesus' point is that how much of a sinner you are isn't going to determine how you die. If what He says about "likewise perishing" applies only to this life, then that would contradict His point. Surely an unrepentant sinner is a worse sinner than a repentant one, and Jesus(under this interpretation) would be saying that unrepentant WILL die brutally in this life("unless you repent, you will all likewise perish"). So which one is it? Were the Galileans murdered by Pilate because they were worse sinners or not? If not(which is what Jesus' "no" implies), then why is He assuring us that we will die in like manner if we do not repent? He Himself said that their brutal death was not due to them being "worse sinners".

If Jesus' words about "likewise perishing" are a reference to final judgment, everything falls into place. Obviously if one ignores God their whole life and never chooses to repent of their sins, when they are resurrected as part of the resurrection to judgment(resurrection of the unrighteous), they will be condemned to death and die violently(by the way, annihilationists do not believe that the wicked are simply "snuffed out of existence", as so many people assume. We believe that all will die painful deaths[some even very excruciating deaths], after which they will have no hope of ever experiencing love or life or anything ever again ad infinitum. Annihilation may not be as frightening as eternal torment, but it certainly isn't warm and fuzzy). Hence, Jesus' words make perfect sense and are in no way lies; *if* you never repent, you *will* certainly die a painful death, except the painful death happens in the next life at final judgment!

However, this clearly contradicts traditional eternal conscious torment/separation; you cannot be dead and alive for eternity in an immortal body simultaneously. Hence my question;

- How do proponents of traditional eternal conscious torment/separation reconcile their beliefs with Jesus' very plain and unequivocal teachings found in Luke 13:1-5?

Comment: I am not well read enough on eternal conscious torment to make a response, but +1 for a good question.

Comment: @LukeHill Thank you so much! Have an awesome day. :)

Comment: Perhaps the distinction needs to be made between **bodily death** and **spiritual death**, where bodily death is the death of your material body through natural process, and spiritual death being separation from God.

Comment: @LukeHill Ah yes, I'm very familiar with that distinction. The problem is, the word "likewise" means "in a similar manner". If unrepentant people will LIKEWISE perish as the Galileans did, then the unrepentant ones undergo literal, physical death, as the Galileans did. Did the Galileans undergo "spiritual death", i.e. separation from God's presence? No. They underwent actual, physical death, and in a violent manner at that. If Jesus says that we will LIKEWISE perish, then He cannot mean "spiritual death", because "spiritual death" is very different from physical death, is it not?

Comment: I’m not sure if likewise has to mean that - I think likewise can also mean “in comparison to”, or “also”, ect,

Comment: Ok sure. Well then, there is nothing comparable between having a building fall onto you and being consciously separated from God's presence for eternity... Those are not similar in any way. :/

Comment: fair enough :), I’m just offering some potential solutions. I’m sure someone else can offer a better one, have a nice day!

Comment: The passage is not about the after life. Jesus' words, here, are about death, not what happens after death. There is nothing to reconcile. If you want to hear cogent argument for the doctrine of eternal torment, this is not the place to start. I think the question lacks focus.

Comment: This is an intriguing application of this passage, +1

Comment: @HoldToTheRod Intriguing? Your comment is "intriguing". This(in my OP) is the only reasonable application of the passage. Someone dies brutally, and Jesus tells His disciples that they will LIKEWISE perish; no one in their right mind can say that Jesus' disciples took that statement to refer to any kind of "death" other than ordinary death(or for you, the "separation between body and spirit"), let alone *eternal conscious separation from God in an immortal, incorruptible body*. Indeed, people will believe whatever they want, regardless of any evidence you present them with.  Appreciate +1!

Comment: @NigelJ Did you notice my, "If I'm not mistaken", "do you?", and "correct?" I'm was not asserting that you believed those things whatsoever. I was thinking that you did, but anyone can clearly see that I was not sure, so they aren't *really* "comments about your beliefs". I wasn't sure what you believed, but I thought I had a rough idea. But it doesn't seem so, so I'm sorry. Have a great day. :))

Comment: @Rajesh  Thank you for your apology. Could you now please delete your inaccurate assessment of my beliefs. Thank you.

Comment: @NigelJ I told you that it wasn't an assessment. You yourself already told me that you have "fully expressed here and elsewhere" what you believe, so why do you care? And the main purpose of my comment was to respond to your comment, which stated "*The passage is not about the afterlife. Jesus' words, here, are about death, not what happens after death.*" The purpose of my comment was **not** in any way whatsoever to make an assessment of your beliefs but to respond to what you had said in your original comment. Once again, you said you've "fully expressed" your beliefs, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Rajesh The comment has now been deleted. So I have deleted my original response to it. I very much care about what is stated, publicly, about my doctrine.

Comment: @NigelJ "*The passage is not about the after life. Jesus' words, here, are about death, not what happens after death.*" Did I mention the afterlife anywhere? I mentioned the next life, that is, the life after the resurrection. My question isn't about what happens after death, because, as you rightly say, Jesus' words here are not about life after death.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's looking for a debate, not answers. The "question" is an answer more or less.

Comment: @Dan Fair enough. To be honest, I was looking for both. I have a thing where I like to know the entirety of my opponent's case/position so that I can make a "steelman" of their argument and refute that. Way too many people would rather not engage to the best of their abilities with their opponent's arguments, and instead, attempt to rebut their *own* easier-to-refute version of their opponent's argument, called a "strawman". I think this is egregious. So, honestly, I was looking for answers so I could rebut them, and I managed to do so, as seen in the comment section of the answer posted here.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that @Rajesh - but it lends itself better to a forum than a Q&A site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The fig tree**

Jesus offers further detail in the parable that immediately follows this passage:

> 6 He spake also this parable; A certain man had a fig tree planted
> in his vineyard; and he came and sought fruit thereon, and found
> none.
>
> 7 Then said he unto the dresser of his vineyard, Behold, these three
> years I come seeking fruit on this fig tree, and find none: cut it
> down; why cumbereth it the ground?
>
> 8 And he answering said unto him, Lord, let it alone this year also,
> till I shall dig about it, and dung it:
>
> 9 And if it bear fruit, well: and if not, then after that thou shalt
> cut it down (Luke 13:6-9)

This is exactly what God is doing with Israel at this time. They have fallen into wickedness & apostasy (e.g. see Matthew 23), and the question is asked, should they just be destroyed now?

No, God spared them a little longer--about 4 decades longer--for the Christian message to be proclaimed from home base in Jerusalem and established in other areas. Then, in AD 70, Jerusalem and the surrounding area was destroyed by Titus.

The destruction of Jerusalem in AD 70 gives force to the "all" in this passage, and is discussed in greater detail by Luke again in chapter 21.

--

**The second death**

That said, I have no problem with the idea that a prophecy or teaching can have multiple applications (see my post [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/62171/39862)). Jesus could doubtless refer to the destruction by Titus and the destruction at the last day in the same message.

However, there is a risk of taking a literal interpretation to the extreme. Does the second death/final punishment of the wicked entail being cut open in the temple & being crushed by a falling building simultaneously? Probably not. As described in Revelation 20, the second death may not be "warm and fuzzy" but it certainly sounds *warm*.

Apparently, then, the manner of death is not the focus here. If Jesus speaks here of spiritual death, believers in ECT/ECS would understand this to mean that Jesus is pronouncing the judgement of spiritual death upon unrepentant sinners.

--

**Conclusion**

The believer in annihilationism and the believer in ECT/ECS would then see this passage in much the same way, while holding differing understandings of what is entailed by *death*. I hold the view that Biblically, death describes separation, and that "dead" and "conscious" are not mutually exclusive properties.--I share a more detailed description of this view [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89717/51818).

It is my view that separation from God *is* an extremely severe & significant consequence, commensurate with the warning given by Jesus in Luke 13.

Comment: "*Does the second death/final punishment of the wicked entail being cut open in the temple & being crushed by a falling building simultaneously*" *Except* Jesus says that they will "likewise perish", **not** that they would "perish *in the exact same way*". The "likewise" indicates *in a similar manner*, as I say in my OP. What do both events have in common? They were both brutal and violent. In saying that they will "likewise perish", Jesus is saying that they will perish in a similarly brutal and violent manner(such is the consequence of the full strength of God's wrath[see Rev. 14:9-11]).

Comment: I just want to point out that, "Jesus' teachings in verses 1-5 precede a parable about the destruction of Jerusalem(verses 6-9), therefore Jesus' teachings in verses 1-5 are also about the destruction of Jerusalem" is not a sound argument whatsoever.

Comment: "*The destruction of Jerusalem in AD 70 gives force to the "all" in this passage*" Actually, no, the "all" disproves that notion that Jesus' teaching here is about the destruction of Jerusalem. Many of Jesus' disciples died before the destruction of Jerusalem(1 Cor. 11:30), hence this teaching would not have had *any* application to many of those hearing it. Jesus' use of "all" would be blatantly misleading. For many of His listeners, whether they repented or not had no bearing on their fate with regards to the destruction of Jerusalem, considering they wouldn't even be alive to experience it!

Comment: You could've gotten away with your interpretation had Jesus said, "No, I tell you; but unless you repent, some[those that will stick around long enough to experience the destruction of Jerusalem] of you will likewise perish". But Jesus instead says, "No, I tell you; but unless you repent, you will ALL likewise perish". If the "perishing" here really IS about the destruction of Jerusalem, as you assert, Jesus' claim that ALL His listeners will perish [in the destruction of Jerusalem] unless they repent is clearly false. Many won't even be around when the destruction of Jerusalem happens!